# How to approach 'four points, two distance, unique shapes' problem, computationally

Tags: python, geometry, computational-geometry

Looking for a way to find solutions for this problem computationally (using program) without pen and paper or plotting.

Find all the ways to arrange four points so that only two distances occur between any two points

In other words, how many ways are there to draw four dots on a piece of paper such that whichever two dots you choose, the distance between these two points is one of two values?

Source : https://www.theguardian.com/science/series/alex-bellos-monday-puzzle

[image: Solutions that satisfy]

Edit 1: Not looking for the solutions themselves. Looking for the computational approach (formal approach) to arrive at the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the only possible complete graphs of four vertices such that the set of edges is partitioned in two subsets. The sizes are (5, 1), (4, 2) and (3, 3).

[image]

Now the equal distance constraints tell you how the geometry must be adjusted. In particular, triangles of the same color must be equilateral and triangles of two colors must be isoceles.

Comment: Hi. thankyou for the answer. 
Just wanted to clarify. In the picture i posted as solution in the original question. 
2nd column, 2nd row image is an example of a unique length sets of (4,2). 
In total three 4,2s are posted in the original solution. 

Does the (4,2) shape you have mentioned, cover this?

Comment: @Rex: absolutely. The graphs convey no geometry, just topology. There are two geometric arrangements corresponding to my second row, second column; that's the only case of several geometries.

Comment: @Rex: by the way, it is questionable that these solutions are "different", they both feature an equilateral triangle and three isocele. Unsure if the (very terse) problem statement specifies that.

Comment: Thanks again for explaining it out. How do you translate these graphs to geometric arrangements?

Comment: @Rex: read my answer. Consider the given graphs and solve the geometric constraints.